# Show given X and Y uncorrelated but not independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

> Let $(X,Y)$ with joint density
>   $$p(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> \pi^{-1}e^{-2x^{2}-y^{2}/2},  & xy \le 0 \\[2ex]
> \pi^{-1}e^{-x^{2}/2-2y^{2}}, & xy \ge 0
> \end{cases}$$
>   Show that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but not independent.

I have already seen easier counterexamples for this und wanted to do a similar approach, thus showing $\Bbb{E}[XY]=\Bbb{E}[X]\Bbb{E}[Y]$ and than $\Bbb{E}[X^{2}Y^{2}]\neq\Bbb{E}[X^{2}]\Bbb{E}[Y^{2}]$ given the structure of the distribution.
But I can't see how this should be possible and how I can derive $\Bbb{E}[X]$ in general from the given information. So I don't really know what I am supposed to show.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The simplest: You know the PDF of $(X,Y)$, deduce the PDF $f_X$ of $X$, deduce $E(X)$ by integrating $xf_(x)$. Slightly more elaborate: compute the PDF of $X$, deduce $E(X)$ by symmetry. Even more elaborate: Realize $(X,Y)$ from $(U,V)$ standard normal and conclude.

Comment: When computing the PDF $f_X$ of $X$: Do I fix $x$ as positiv and differentiate between $y\le 0$ and $y\ge 0$ ? And if I do so, how will I deal with the two cases when computing $E(X)$ ?

Comment: First question: yes, to compute $f_X$, one fixes $x$ and integrates $p(x,y)$ over $y$. Second question: to compute $E(X)$, integrate $xf_X(x)$ on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct way is to compute $E[XY]=\iint xyp(x,y) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy}$ and $E[X]=\int x \int p(x,y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}$, etc.

Perhaps a slicker way is the following. Draw $Z_1\sim N(0,1)$ and $Z_2 \sim N(0,1/4)$. Then, let
$$(X,Y) := \begin{cases}(Z_1,Z_2) & \text{if } Z_1Z_2 \ge 0\\(Z_2,Z_1) & \text{if }Z_1Z_2 \le 0.\end{cases}$$
I think you can show that the density of $(X,Y)$ is exactly the one you specify in your problem.

So, $E[XY]=E[Z_1Z_2]=E[Z_1]E[Z_2]=0$. Also, with a lot of symmetry arguments, we have $$E[X] =\frac{1}{2} E[Z_1 \mid Z_1Z_2 \ge 0] + \frac{1}{2} E[Z_2 \mid Z_1 Z_2 \le 0] = 0,$$
and similarly $E[Y]=0$. So $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

However, I think repeating the above argument for the second moments will yield $E[X^2 Y^2] = \frac{1}{4} \ne \left(\frac{5}{8}\right)^2 = E[X^2]E[Y^2]$, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I willl first try the brute force computation and have a look at your more elegant way after this, as I am not that familiar with Normal Distribution and typical arguments about it.

But it does indeed look more beautiful and cleaner